# How can I eliminate the bad anti-aliasing or blending on the left side of my SVG layers?

Tags: html, svg

Sorry for the garish colors, but it most clearly shows the bad blending with this combination.

On the left side of the inner circle, there is a dark line where the blue meets the red. But on the right half of the inner circle, there is not. This is happening in Chrome, FF, and IE11.

Any idea why?

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="500" height="500">
  <circle fill="red" cx="250" cy="215" r="165"/>
  <circle fill="#2994FF" cx="250" cy="215" r="100"/>
</svg>
```

Picture version:

[image]

Comment: can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @RD Sure thing. Updated. Did the code snippet not work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you think you are seeing is not actually real.  It is an optical illusion caused mostly by the contrast change between the two colours.  Dark to light and then light to dark.

The layout of the [subpixels on your monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) may be contributing as well - I'm not sure on that.

If we create a magnified version of the two edges next to one another, you should see that those strong dark and light borders are not actually there.

[image]

Comment: If it were merely an optical illusion, I would think it would be consistent around the perimeter. I think you're correct about the subpixels, though! I should've thought to zoom rather than just make the circle bigger via the SVG canvas! Thanks = )